# WM_ENABLE default processing

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have problem in my control window. How to respond to the WM_ENABLE message?

I have bool flag bEnable which controls WM_ENABLE message:

```
LRESULT WINAPI OnEnable(HWND hWindow, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT lReturn = 0;
    BOOL bEnabled = (BOOL)wParam;
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    g_bEnabled = bEnabled;
    InvalidateRect(hWindow, NULL, TRUE);
    return lReturn;
}
```

But this not affect setting WS_DISABLED by SetWindowLong.

So how I make my OnEnable handler reflects this changes?

Is proper way:

```
LONG lStyles = GetWindowLong(hWindow, GWL_STYLE);

if (bEnable)
{
        lStyles = lStyles & ~WS_DISABLED;
        g_bEnable = TRUE;
}
else
{
         lStyles = lStyles | WS_DISABLED;
         g_bEnable = FALSE;
}
```

or is another way?

Comment: Wow, One downvote for 3 views, why?

Comment: Don't use SetWindowsLong to change the enable state, use EnableWindow.

Comment: `WM_ENABLE` is simply a notification message, you don't have to **do** anything. The `WS_DISABLED` bit is changed for you.

Comment: @RossRidge: Thanks for comment, but if someone else use SetWindowLong to change WS_DISABLED, my boolen flag dont reflect this.

Comment: Then that someone else is making a mistake and there's not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`EnableWindow(hwnd, enable)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  to enable/disable window

Use [`IsWindowEnabled(hwnd)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check if window is enabled or disabled.

Calling `Invalidate` after enable/disable may not have any visible effect. For example if there is a OK button, the OK button may still appear as enabled even if window is disabled. If you want to disable the child controls then use the following:

```
HWND child = GetWindow(hwnd, GW_CHILD);
while (child)
{
    EnableWindow(child, enable);
    child = GetWindow(child, GW_HWNDNEXT);
}
```

The following functions will work too, but there is no reason to use them over `EnableWindow` and `IsWindowEnabled`

```
//don't use
BOOL enabled = !(GetWindowLong(hbutton, GWL_STYLE) & WS_DISABLED);

//disable - don't use
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) | WS_DISABLED);

//enable - don't use
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_DISABLED);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I know EnableWindow and IsWindowEnabled. But my problem is related to question: Is better repond WM_ENABLE message or is better always check WS_DISABLED bit. Also for my control InvalidateRect works perfect, with only one problem and this is this question.

Comment: Just use `EnableWindow` and `IsWindowEnabled` as stated in [doucmentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): *To change this after a window has been created, use the EnableWindow function*

Comment: You dont understand. I dont use EnableWindow, because my control is used 3rd party people. If they use EnableWindow or SendMessage(WM_ENABLE), I dont care. I have only problem, if someone trying use SetWindowLong(WS_DISABLED).

Comment: I understand your question. As stated in comments and documentation the correct way is to use `EnableWindow`. You will have to catch `WM_STYLECHANGED` if you want to detected messages sent as `SetWindowLong(... WS_DISABLED)` but it's not done that way.

Comment: I have WM_STYLECHANGED handler, so this is OK. So you recommend always use IsWindowEnabled and forgot about WM_ENABLE. Yes?

Comment: I think you do need `WM_ENABLE`. I assume you have a custom control and you want to repaint the control when it is disabled. Other programs will most likely call `EnableWindow` which results in `WM_ENABLE` message --- In the off chance that the other program is badly written and uses `SetWindowLong(... WS_DISABLED)`, you would need to check `WM_STYLECHANGED` as well as `WM_ENABLE`